# How can I stop git from use of GUI PGP key manager when signing a commit?

Tags: git, signature, gnupg, gpg-signature, gpg-agent

I am working in terminal via ssh.  When I commit, I am asked for a password to unlock my private key.  As long as I have no graphical session running everything works as expected.

The problem is that when I have an graphical session running (XFCE), I am asked for the password in that session rather in the terminal.  How can I force git/gpg2 to ask for password in the terminal when the graphical session is running?

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need a [`gpg-agent.conf`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html) with a [`--pinentry-program`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#index-pinentry_002dformatted_002dpassphrase) set to `/usr/bin/pinentry-tty` (as [in here](https://superuser.com/a/521027/141)). Add `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Or, as [suggested here](https://superuser.com/a/1712225/141), call gpg with:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --export-secret-keys -a | less
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no `pinentry-tty`, thus used `pinentry-curses` as in the linked answer.